# Show that following series converges uniformly on $[0,1]$ if and only if $α > 1$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, uniform-convergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{{x^α}}{1+n^2x^2}$$$α>0$

I tried solving it using Weierstrass M test but i didn't got $M_n$ as function of $n$.

Comment: Comparing the series with an integral, one sees that, when $N\to\infty$, $$\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{x^a}{1+n^2x^2}\sim x^a\int_N^\infty\frac{dt}{t^2x^2}=\frac1Nx^{a-2}$$ hence the convergence should be uniform on $[0,1]$ for $$a\geqslant2$$ Are you sure about the condition $$a>1\ ?$$

Comment: @Did It appears that's O.K. $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^\alpha}{1+n^2x^2}\le \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac12 (2-\alpha)^{1-\alpha/2}\alpha^{\alpha/2}\frac1{n^\alpha}$$ for $\alpha\in(1,2]$.

Comment: @user539887 Hmmm... nifty. And even, for every $a\in(1,2]$, $$\frac{x^a}{1+n^2x^2}\leqslant\frac1{n^a}$$